# How to fix this 404 soft error?

Tags: htaccess, 404

I have a static HTML website.

`www.example.com/?12345` (this page doesn't exist) redirects to `www.example.com` and `www.example.com/page.html?12345` redirects to `www.example.com/page.html`. I don't know why this happens.

Google said this is a soft 404 error and `www.example.com/page.html?12345` should return a 404 response not a 200 OK response.

How can I fix this ?

Here's my *.htaccess*:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Cache
# 1 month
<filesMatch ".(jpg|jpeg|png|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, private"
</filesMatch>
# 3 days
<filesMatch ".(txt|css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=259200, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
# 10 min
<filesMatch ".(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3600, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"
</filesMatch>

# Include php
<Files contact.htm>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 htm
</Files>
```

Comment: Please share your .htaccess file.

Comment: Please add it to your question (no comment) with proper formatting.

Comment: Added to my question.

Comment: Yeah... these were not "redirects". The query string parameters are ignored by default.

Answer (score 3):

No idea where you got that *soft error* notice.

**The behavior you see is completely normal.** If you have a page and someone adds parameters to it, any parameter not used by the page are and should be ignored.

If you only want naked URLs to work and all URLs with parameter to return a 404 then you will have to **add specific htaccess rules for that**. Something like:

```
RewriteCond ${QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L,NC]
```

Comment: The soft error notice referred to in this question would have been from Google Webmaster Tools. A soft error is essentially a Page-not-found error page but without the appropriate HTTP 404 code in the response headers.